# Firebase data retrieval java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
    "Account1" : 
    {
        Push_key(): { Carplate: "ABC1234" }
        Push_key(): { Carplate: "ABC" }
        Push_key(): { Carplate: "A" }
    }
}
```

This is how the database looks like.
I would like to retrieve the third data which contains `"A"` alone ONLY.
I am using `startAt()` and `endAt()` for data retrieval:

```
Query query = ref.child("Account1").orderByChild("Carplate").startAt("A").endAt("A"+"\uf8ff");
```

But it returns all 3 records. (I think its due to they are all started at `"A"`.)
Need help! Please!

Comment: You should be able to test your theory on your own by changing the values so that they don't all start with A and see what happens.

Comment: It works if there is only 1 that starts with "A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the `equalTo()` method for this (from the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries)):

> The equalTo() method allows you to filter based on exact matches. As is the case with the other range queries, it will fire for each matching child node.

To adapt it to your query you might try:

```
Query query = ref.child("Account1").orderByChild("Carplate").equalTo("A");
```

Comment: I actually tried equalTo("A") and even limitToFirst(1), still it returns all of them. I will keep on trying!

Comment: I think equalTo() works but at the same time i have other problem. Well thanks for the reply!